# About the Lacunary $f(z)$ such that $f(z) = b^{-1}(a(z)), a(z) = \sum_{0<n} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(4n)!} , b(z) = \sum_{0<n} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(4n+3)!}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, inverse-function, analytic-continuation, lacunary-series

Let

$$a(z) = \sum_{0<n} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(4n)!}$$

$$b(z) = \sum_{0<n} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(4n+3)!}$$

Both have a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$.

Let $c(z)$ be the series reversion of $b(z)$.

So $c(z)$ is the functional inverse of $b(z)$.

See : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Does $f(z) = c(a(z))$ also have a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$ ?

Why is that ?

Notice $a$ and $b$ seem very similar, so you would expect $c(a(z))$ to at least converge in a larger radius ?

To imagine how this could perhaps work ,

Say $d(z)$ is a taylor series of the functional inverse of $a(z)$.

$$d(a(z)) = a(d(z)) = z$$

$$c(z) = a_0 + a_1 d(z) + a_2 d(z)^2 + a_3 d(z)^3 + ...$$

Then clearly

$$f(z) = c(a(z)) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + ...$$

And this could have any radius in principle, it just depends on the $a_n$.

---

Another thought.

How can a function converge outside its natural boundary ?

Well there are summability methods, lambert series etc.

But even if that fails the question above makes sense, just like

$a(d(z)) = z = b(c(z))$ everwhere since they are functional inverses.

Also sums like

$$ h(z) = \sum _{0<n} \frac{z^n}{(1 - z^n) n^4}$$

have a natural boundary, yet converge outside it as well.

Another example :

$$j(z) = a(z) - a(z^2/2)$$

$a(z)$  has a radius 1 and boundary natural boundary there.

$(z^2/2)$ has a radius $\sqrt 2$ and a natural boundary there.

However

$$j(2) = a(2) - a(4/2) = a(2) - a(2) = 0$$

So $j(z)$ has a taylor series with radius $1$ , natural boundary $1$, but $j(2) = 0$.

And there also ideas like $\frac{a(z)^2}{b(z)^2 + a(z) + 1}$ and such stuff.

Some people even consider extending these natural boundaries with "infinite numbers" or noncomplex numbers.

So many ideas exist.

Limits of truncated series is also an idea.

Comment: How does $a(z)$ behave as $z$ approaches a point $z_0$ at which it cannot be analytically continued?

Comment: @TedShifrin see the edit.